# Mapping from "int" to corresponding permutation value?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I ran across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382596/how-can-i-efficiently-use-threads-in-this-case) this morning.

Basically that question is about data which has to create permutations for 6 values; each one ranging from 1 to 38.

So, first permutation would be

```
1 1 1 1 1 1      [ permutation 1 ]
1 1 1 1 1 2      [ permutation 2 ]
1 1 1 1 1 3...   [ permutation 3 ]
```

to end much later with

```
38 38 38 38 38 38 [ permutation 38^^6 ]
```

The output is simply created by 6 nested loops, each counting from 1 to 38; and within the inner-most loop, you print the 6 loop counters.

Now I am wondering about the math behind that; and out of curiosity: what would be the "function" that

1. computes the "permutation index", given a any permutation 1 2 3 4 5 6
2. Probably more interesting: that takes an "index", such as 102382; and tells me the corresponding permutation output

Any idea anybody?

Comment: Since you can reuse values across all positions, wouldn't this simply be a "base 39" formatting of the value? Or Base 38 if you can't use 0.

Comment: A permutation is defined as an ordering of the numbers 1 to N, just saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works exactly like a change of base (binar, octal or hex).
The first one question simply:
 1*38^6 + 2*38^5 + 3*38^4 + 4*38^3 +...+6*38^0
The second one reversed:
102382 mod 38... recursively
**UPDATE**
Let us assume we want change 10 to base 2:

```
10/2=5 remainder(modulus)  **0** 
5/2=2 remainder           **1**
2/2=1 remainder           **0**
1/2=0 remainder           **1**
```

backwards is  **1010**
general gave a M to change in base B, just divide M by B ,  and the remainder are going to be the digit in the new base

Comment: I am kinda slow today; if you don't mind rolling out that "reverse" a bit more. Will probably result in not only upvoting but also  accepting your answer then ;-)

Comment: It is the algorithm for change of base. Let's assume we want convert 9 to binary. The string get built backwards. So we start: